# How to determine for which parameter values in a linear system, vector set spans $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> For vectors $v_1=(2,1,-1), v_2=(-m,-1,3), v_3=(-3,2,m+1), v_4=(1,2,1)$ determine for which values of $m$ the set {$v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$} spans $\mathbb{R^3}$.

As far as I understand the problem is equivalent to finding whether one or more solutions exist for the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-m&-3&1 \\
1 &-1&2&2\\
-1&3&m+1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that is if vector $\underline b = (b_1, b_2, b_3)$ is a linear combination of {$v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$}. So am I correct that I need to solve for which $m$ the following matrix has solution/s:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-m&-3&1&b_1 \\
1 &-1&2&2&b_2\\
-1&3&m+1&1&b_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm particularly not sure if only one solution exists or infinitely many can exist for the span to exist.

Comment: Do you know how to find the dimension of the column space of a matrix?

Comment: I don't think so. The most advanced topic we've covered is linear in/dependecy

Comment: In that case, you know that the set of vectors must be linearly dependent. How might you go about finding a linearly independent subset?

Comment: I'd have to find a solution to the homogenous system such that there's only a trivial solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note, the system is underdetermined — three equations with four unknowns — so it can't possibly have a unique solution. It either has no solutions or infinitely many solutions.

So when you say `the problem is equivalent to finding whether one or more solutions exist`, you're essentially correct. But for this question we don't care how many solutions exist, i.e we don't care to distinguish between "one" or "infinitely many". The real question is: do solutions (any number of them) exist or not?

Another side note is that the wording `solutions exist for the matrix` is meaningless. Matrices don't have solutions; equations do. Yes, matrices can represent systems of equations, but they can represent lots of other things too. So to talk about solutions, you should be talking about (systems of) equations — which, in particular, can be represented using matrices.

Now, to your actual question. Yes, you question is to determine whether for any vector $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ the system of equations represented by your second matrix as the augmented matrix has solutions (doesn't matter how many). But a somewhat easier approach would be not to use such an generic vector $\mathbf{b}$, so that you wouldn't have to do all the work in the last column. Instead, use the following theorem:

> A set of $p$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if the rank of the matrix with these vectors as columns (that's your first matrix) is $n$.

Comment: @ zipirovich: thank you for a great explanation and advice on the wording. Unfortunately, I can't use the theorem you suggested as we didn't get to rank yet. By the way, if a system is linearly independent does this mean it spans the given space?

Comment: @ zipirovich: is it correct that in this example the vectors span $\mathbb{R^3}$ for any value of $m$ because after reducing the matrix we can't possibly get a contradiction row and there're more variables than equations?

Comment: @Yos:  "if a system is linearly independent does this mean it spans the given space" -- no. Being linearly independent and spanning the entire space are two different properties. They are equivalent to each other **ONLY** for a system of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. when the number of vectors is equal to the dimension of the space. But this is not the case here, as we have $4$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In fact, since we have more vectors than the dimension, they definitely are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Yos: No, not for all $m$. As Stefan Böttner determined in his answer, for $m=4$ they don't span the entire $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you do row reduction of the smaller matrix, with $m=4$ the last row turns into all zeroes. So in the augmented matrix this will be a contradiction row for some vectors $\mathbf{b}$, if the bottom entry in the augmented column is nonzero.

Comment: @ zipirovich: but then how come we see that there can't be a contradiction row if we check here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B2,-m,-3,1,+a%7D,%7B1,-1,2,2,+b%7D,%7B-1,3,m%2B1,1,+c%7D%7D   if anything if $m=-5$ then we have division by $0$

Comment: @Yos: Short answer: if anything, it proves only one thing -- that we can't trust technology, such as WolframAlpha, too much! WolframAlpha assumed that all operations it wants to do are well-defined. So its solution that you linked to is **NOT** valid for $m=-5$ or $m=4$. Of course, we can't divide by $0$, but WolframAlpha divided by variable expressions anyway. For $m=-5$ or $m=4$ its solution makes no sense, so for either of them you have to plug in this value of $m$ specifically and redo all the work.

Comment: @ zipirovich: thank you very much, at last I was able to arrive to echelon form and then indeed if $m=4$ then not necessarily we have a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the determinant of the matrix obtained by removing one column, e.g. the third one:
$$\det \left( \begin{matrix}2 & -m & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 2 \\ -1 & 3 & 1 \end{matrix}  \right)=3m-12$$
Since this is nonzero for $m \neq 4$, the columns of this matrix (and thus also the columns of your original matrix) span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

As it turns out, $m=4$ is always a root of the determinant, no matter which of the columns you eliminate. Hence $v_1,\ldots,v_4$ do **not** span $\mathbb{R}^3$ for $m=4$. As you can see from the derivation, for $m \neq 4$ the linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_4$ for a point $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is not unique.

Comment: @ Stefan Böttner: thanks for the suggestion unfortunately we didn't learn determinants yet. However according to Wolfram Alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B2,-m,-3,1,+a%7D,%7B1,-1,2,2,+b%7D,%7B-1,3,m%2B1,1,+c%7D%7D) we can reduce the matrix to echelon form and then it looks like contradiction row doesn't exist and we have more variable than equations so it has infinitely many solutions and any $m$ will result in a solution. You're saying that there will be solutions only for $m \neq 4$ right?

Answer (score 1):

You’re on the right track: the given set of vectors spans $\mathbb R^3$ if every vector $\mathbf b\in\mathbb R^3$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors. As you’ve already stated, this is equivalent to asking if the vector equation $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ has a solution for all $\mathbf b$, where $A$ is the matrix with the given vectors as its columns. For this to be true, the column space of $A$ must be all of $\mathbb R^3$, so we proceed to determine the dimension of the column space via row-reduction. Start by swapping the first two rows, then subtract twice the first row from the second and add the first row to the third to produce $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&2\\0&2-m&-7&-3\\0&2&m+3&3\end{bmatrix}.$$ (I started by swapping rows to avoid propagating $m$’s into other rows.) Next, swap the second and third rows so that we’re not dividing by $2-m$, which might be zero, add $(m-2)/2$ times the second row to the third and then multiply the third row by 2 to tidy things up a bit: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&2\\0&2&m+3&3\\0&0&m^2+m-20&3m-12\end{bmatrix}.$$ We have pivots in the first two rows. For the column space to be three-dimensional, we also need a pivot in the third row. To put it another way, the column space will be less than all of $\mathbb R^3$ if the last row is all zeros. This occurs when $m$ is a solution to the system $$\begin{align}m^2+m-20&=0\\3m-12&=0.\end{align}$$ Therefore, the set of vectors spans $\mathbb R^3$ unless $m=4$.

Comment: @ amd: thank you very much! I managed to get to almost the same row-reduced form as you did.